# Hibernate @JoinColumnOrFormula error

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to map an entity through JoinTable, but that didn't work so I am now trying to use the @JoinColumnOrFormula annotation, but I keep getting an error. The models are `User`, `House`, `UserHouseMap`. I want to use `user.name` (non-primary key & non-unique) to retrieve a record from `user_house_map` using `user_house_map.user_name` (primary key)  & retrieve the associated `House` using the other key `house_name`, which should reference `house.house_name` (primary key)

The DB structure is weird, but it is necessary & cannot be changed at this point.

Here is what I have tried. This may be completely incorrect since theres no proper documentation on how to use JoinColumnOrFormula

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Expose
public Long id;

@Expose
@Required
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT user_name as name from user_housing_map where user_name = name)", referencedColumnName="house_name")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="house_name", referencedColumnName="house_name"))
})
public House house;
```

NOTE: I intially tried the following mapping

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(
    name="user_house_map",
    joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="user_name", referencedColumnName="name"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="house_name", referencedColumnName="house_name"))
public House house;
```

But I got this error

```
Unable to find column with logical name: name in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(users)
```

Here are the DB schemas for all 3 models

**Users**

```
                               Table "public.users"
        Column         |            Type             |          Modifiers          
-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------
 name                  | character varying(255)      |
 id                    | integer                     | not null 
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "housing_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES user_house_map(user_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**Houses**

```
                Table "public.houses"
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
---------------+------------------------+-----------
 house_name    | character varying(255) | not null
 address       | text                   | 
 city          | text                   | 
 state         | text                   | 
 zip           | integer                | 
 zip_ext       | integer                | 
 phone         | text                   | 
Indexes:
    "house_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (house_name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_house_map" CONSTRAINT "house_map_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (house_name) REFERENCES house(house_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**UserHouseMap**

```
         Table "public.user_house_map"
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 user_name   | character varying(255) | not null
 house_name  | character varying(255) | not null
Indexes:
    "user_house_map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_name)
    "user_house_map_house_key" btree (house_name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "user_house_map_house_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (house_name) REFERENCES houses(house_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "housing_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES user_house_map(user_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was for the User class then, you should just use the JoinTable annotation with back referenced columns:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(
    name="user_house_map",
    joinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="user_name", referencedColumnName="name"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
    @JoinColumn(name="house_name", referencedColumnName="house_name"))
public House house;
```

But joins that are not over @ID column are generally not supported by JPA. Luckily for you they seems to be working with hibernate.

Comment: Btw, that is what I initially tried, but I got the following error `Unable to find column with logical name: name in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(users)`. I will update the question with this note